# Looking for a more efficient/pythonic way to sum tuples in a list, and compute an average

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, urllib3

I am trying to do some basic computations with data from the web. For this cause, I have found some code that extracts begin and end years for Rembrandt works. It saves it in a list

```
date_list =[(work['datebegin'], work['dateend']) for work in `rembrandt2_parsed['records']]`
```

date_list is a list containing the tuples with begin and end years for some Rembrandt works in the Harvard Art Museum. For the sake of completeness, it looks like this:

```
[(0, 0), (1648, 1648), (1637, 1647), (1626, 1636), (0, 0), (1638, 1638), (1635, 1635), (1634, 1634), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
```

Now I want to do some basic computations, **I want to sum over this list of tuples, and compute the average of the years when they are not null**. I came up with a solution:

```
datebegin =0
date_end =0
count_begin =0
count_end =0

for x, y in date_list:
    if x !=0:
        datebegin +=x
        count_begin +=1
    if y != 0:
        date_end +=y
        count_end +=1

final_date_begin = datebegin/count_begin #value = year 1636
final_date_end = date_end/count_end #value = year 1639
```

But I think this can be done much more efficient/pythonic. In the first place because I seem to need a lot of code for such a simple task, and in the second place because I need to initialize 4(!) global vars if I do it in this way. **Could someone enlighten me and show me a more efficient way to solve this?**

Comment: The average of the not-null values in the list of tuples.

Comment: Please remove all the code that shows how you get the data. That's irrelevant. Add a sample input and the *literal* expected output, not (only) a description of the expected output in words. Thanks.

Comment: @timgeb Will do.

Comment: using `tuple(map(lambda y: sum(y) / float(len(y)), zip(*List)))`  gives   `(981.8, 983.8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy` to solve this:

```
import numpy as np

result = list(np.ma.masked_equal(date_list, 0).mean(axis=0))
```

Here we thus first store the `date_list` in an array, next we mask out the zero values, and then we calculate the average over the first axis.

For your sample data, we obtain:

```
>>> list(np.ma.masked_equal(date_list, 0).mean(axis=0))
[1636.3333333333333, 1639.6666666666667]
```

**Performance**: for a list containing 100'000 2-tuples, generated with:

```
from random import randint

date_list = [(randint(0, 10), randint(0, 10)) for _ in range(100000)]
```

we repeated this function 1'000 times, and obtain:

```
>>> timeit(f, number=1000)
51.31010195999988
```

so locally, this works for a 100'000×2 "matrix" in 51.3 ms per run.

Answer (score 2):

Non-numpy solution:

```
lst = [(0, 0), (1648, 1648), (1637, 1647), (1626, 1636), (0, 0), (1638, 1638), (1635, 1635), (1634, 1634), (0, 0), (0, 0)]

print(sum(x[0] for x in lst) / sum(x[0] != 0 for x in lst))
# 1636.3333333333333
print(sum(x[1] for x in lst) / sum(x[1] != 0 for x in lst))
# 1639.6666666666667
```

Answer (score 2):

Numpy and list comprehensions are your friend here.

```
import numpy as np  
date_list = [(0, 0), (1648, 1648), (1637, 1647), (1626, 1636), (0, 0), 
             (1638, 1638), (1635, 1635), (1634, 1634), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
final_date_begin = np.mean([x for x, y in date_list if not x == 0])
final_date_end = np.mean([y for x, y in date_list if not y == 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

In pure Python

```
starts = [s for s, e in date_list for if s and e]
ends = [e for s, e in date_list for if s and e]

start_avg = sum(starts) / len(starts)
end_avg = sum(ends) / len(ends)
```